# Nuxt 3 extending a project causes an error

Tags: nuxt.js, extends

Whenever I try to extend another Nuxt 3 project using:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({   // this is inside the nuxt.config.ts in `main-project`
    extends: [
        '../test-extend'
    ]
})
```

I get an error saying that a module could not be found (for example: Cannot start nuxt:  Cannot find module '@vueuse/nuxt')

My directory structure looks like this:

```
 
├──  test-extend/
└──  main-project/
```

Am I doing something wrong? I tried putting the `test-extend` project inside the `main-project` to see whether the path wasn't a problem but that didn't help either...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some experimenting I found out that the error disappears when I add the dependencies of the parent layer (`test-extend`) to the `main-project`. This might seem like a super obvious solution in retrospect, however, I think it is a bug because the documentation mentions "Create Nuxt module presets" as one of the [features of Nuxt Layers](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/layers#layers) & I don't think this is really "creating a module preset" if I have to remember what dependencies are installed in the layer & then add them manually to the new project anyway.

Comment: Agree, should not have to manually install the dependency of the extended project. If we remove usage of the extended project in the future, we have to remember to uninstall the dependency as well. Quite inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** You can now instruct Nuxt to install the dependencies of the extended project in the config, no need to install all the dependencies in both projects anymore.

this snippet is taken from Nuxt's docs for layers:

> When using git remote sources, if a layer has npm dependencies and you wish to install them, you can do so by specifying install: true in your layer options.

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  extends: [
    ['github:username/repoName', { install: true }]
  ]
})
```

Comment: Does that work for local layers, though? Mine aren't on GitHub